# Using carrierwave_backgrounder along with carrierwave-video, email notifications

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, carrierwave

I have my site configured so that it will automatically render different versions of a video in the background. It's actually working really well. If the video is successful in the three different transcodes it will send a success email. However, if it generates an error, it will send a failure email. The issue that I'm having is that i'm trying to pass self through to the Action Mailer so that I can atleast give the name of the video that is successful or failed. However, it appears that self is null.

model

```
  def video_success(format, opts)
    VideoMailer.video_success(self).deliver
  end
  def video_rescue(format, opts)
    VideoMailer.video_error(self).deliver
  end
```

uploader

```
version :mp4 do
    process :encode_video => [:mp4, callbacks: {rescue: :video_rescue}  ]
    def full_filename(for_file)
      "#{File.basename(for_file, File.extname(for_file))}.mp4"
    end
end


version :webm do
    process :encode_video => [:webm, callbacks: { after_transcode: :video_success, rescue: :video_rescue }]
    def full_filename(for_file)
      "#{File.basename(for_file, File.extname(for_file))}.webm"
    end
end
```

Any thoughts on how this can be accomplished? Also, it would be best that if there was an error, to return the error message that is generated.

Secondly, each User model has an email address. The user who uploads the video should receive the email address. However, I'm having issues using current_user within the model. I'm thinking that it also has something to do with the backgrounder since that information is not passed over to the background process.

Comment: Could you give more information about your model? Did you have add mounted field in attr_accessible?

Comment: For current_user in model, there is a good discussion about it here: http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/47-fetch-current-user-in-models The given solution works but "spyromus" is right. Up to you to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a class method to the end of the background processor

`process_in_background :video, ParanoidVideo`

In the models directory, I created `paranoid_video.rb` and referenced the delivery of the mail. This way, the Carrierwave_Backgrounder is handling the success method instead of Carrierwave-Video.

```
class ParanoidVideo < ::CarrierWave::Workers::ProcessAsset
  def success(job)
    VideoMailer.video_backgrounder(job).deliver
  end
end
```

I ended up creating a new field in the database called `last_updated_by` and use this to return which user is being called. Granted, this is an extra call to the database when the user is being pulled, but I find that this is sufficient for my purposes. The background processor statically returns consistent handlers so I was able to just split the lines and gsub to get the ID. `to_i` will pull the first numerical value which is always the Video id in my case.

```
  def video_backgrounder(job)
    @job = job
    @video = Video.find_by_id(@job.handler.split("\n")[2].gsub("id: '","").to_i)
    @user = User.find_by_id(@video.last_updated_by)
    mail(:to => @user.email, :subject => "Video Transcoding Successful")
  end
```